# How to make transparent control show form's background image underneath on MDI form

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, transparency

I have an MDI form with a background, and a picture box in the upper left of a logo.  The transparent areas of the logo correctly show through to the form's background image on a regular form, but on an MDI form it shows grey underneath.

How can I make the transparent areas of the picture box show the background instead of the form underneath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not how I wanted to solve the problem, but I docked a panel in the form and used that as the background instead of the form's background.  I hate using extra container controls for stuff like this so if someone has a better answer please share.

Comment: Well, this turned out to be a horrible solution for me because the mdi form is actually inheriting this stuff from a base form and doing this makes it so I can't move my controls around for some weird reason.  Any other ideas?